# Facebook app: send message to users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if theres a way to make my app send any type of message/notification to a user with a certain uid. Anything but posting to the users wall will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can request the email extended permission to get the current user's email address and you can email them that way. To send a message to a users friends (without posting to their wall), the only current option is the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) in the javascript sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Did you gave **Send Dialog** a try, here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

The only limitation is you have to have a url along with. The notification goes in the message timeline. Basically it is meant for sending content, not bare messages.